# htaccess redirect to https://www url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, redirect

I have to redirect my site on https://www.example.com using htaccess.

I have used many solutions but when I remove "s" from https my site runs on http & when I only run the www.example.com then it will run on http it works only with the "example.com".

Solution which I have used is mentioned below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Does any one have a magic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
# http(s)://domain  ->  https://www.domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: with this solution got the issue of too many redirections loop how to resolve it?

Comment: The problem is not here. You must have another application or configuration, which again changes the domain.

Comment: I'm using the codeigniter framework where i have only set my base url.